# Change xlink:href attribute in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, svg

I want to load an image file inside of an SVG-.
It works well in Firefox and IE but for some reason not in Chrome.

```
svgItem.setAttribute("xlink:href", "http://link/to.png");
```

Is there some workarround?

Comment: Just an idea, but did you try `setAttributeNS`?

Comment: What do I have to pick as namespace param? I've tried "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" without any success.

Comment: No, you need the xlink namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setAttributeNS does the Job!

```
svgItem.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","xlink:href", "http://link/to.png");
```

Comment: Note that this is just required when you set the attribute the first time. Modifying an already existing attribute like `xlink:href` won't require us to use `setAttributeNS` instead of `setAttribute`.

Comment: @KingKing I'd recommend going with `setAttributeNS` for any attribute that has a prefix, see http://w3c.github.io/dom/#dom-element-setattribute.

Comment: @ErikDahlström thanks but I won't. I understand that the setAttribute works on the ***attribute node***. This node already contains information about the namespace because it was created before with `setAttributeNS`. The link you give me is not helpful to me.

Comment: @KingKing ok you're technically right, though what's the harm in using `setAttributeNS` for such attributes when it works 100% of the time?